# Issue in saving the dropdown list in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the dropdown list in magento admin.But i am not getting how to save the dropdown list.I have added the dropdown list in below files.Please any one can Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. i see issue in your select box name it should be "bloodgroup" as per your code in controller for save

```
$fieldset->addField("Bloodgroup", "select", array(
                "label"     => Mage::helper("serviceprovider")->__("Bloodgroup"),
                "name"      => "bloodgroup", 
                "values"    => array(
                  '-1'=> array( 'label' => 'Please Select....', 'value' => '-1'),
                  '1' => array(
                           'value'=> array(array('value'=>'2' , 'label' => 'A') , array('value'=>'3' , 'label' =>'AB'), array('value'=>'4' , 'label' => 'AB+') , array('value'=>'5' , 'label' =>'AB-'), array('value'=>'6' , 'label' => 'A+') , array('value'=>'7' , 'label' =>'B+') , array('value'=>'8' , 'label' => 'O+ ') , array('value'=>'9' , 'label' =>'O-')),

                         ), 
                ), 
                ));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    "values"    => array(
                   array( 'label' => 'Please Select....', 'value' => '-1'),

                 array('value'=>'2' , 'label' => 'A') ,

     array('value'=>'3' , 'label' =>'AB'),
 array('value'=>'4' , 'label' => 'AB+') ,
 array('value'=>'5' , 'label' =>'AB-'),
 array('value'=>'6' , 'label' => 'A+') ,
 array('value'=>'7' , 'label' =>'B+') , array('value'=>'8' , 'label' => 'O+ ') ,
 array('value'=>'9' , 'label' =>'O-'),

                         ),
```

or you can add it like that too

```
'values' => array('-1'=>'Please Select....',2=>'A',3=>'AB',4=>'AB+'),
```

Comment: If you see my form I have added in the same way but when i am saving the dropdown list it is not saving.

Comment: no they are not same you add values on main array replace it and then check..

Comment: Once can you check in save action in service Controller.php file.

Comment: i checked your save action there is no problem there the problem was in the form that i fixed

Comment: Changed the form as you said but it not saving.

Comment: @Mouni check my answer

Comment: @Mouni you can up vote my answer

Comment: @MineshPatel well catch

Comment: @Mouni its "Minesh" not "Manish"